# Better way for frame by frame animation in Corona SDK

Tags: animation, graphics, sdk, coronasdk, frame

I need to show an animation after splash screen before the main app menu appears. The designer made animation in a 3D software and exported it frame by frame in PNG images.

I search around and find MovieClip library suggested by someone. I used it and runs fine in Corona's emulator but it crashes in device. I guess the issue is with the memory.

The images are of dimension 2048 x 1536 (designed for iPad retina screen) and size is around 30KB in average. There are around 300 images. So I can't use spritesheet too.

Please suggest if there is better way to do this kind of animations in Corona. I searched for days and even posted on their forum, no good result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Corona SDK does not support video playback (unless it uses a native window). If movieclips isn't working, you could try to load in each image and then use an enterframe function to loop through them.

Something like

```
--table to hold images you are on
local localImages = {}

--how many images in splash
local totalImages = 100

--create images
for i = 1, totalImages, 1 do
    --create different images. Change these to load in images using newImageRect of course
    localImages[i] = display.newRect( display.contentWidth*.5, display.contentHeight*.5, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    localImages[i]:setFillColor( i/totalImages )

    --make images invisible
    localImages[i].isVisible = false
end


--timer
local myTimer = 1

--first frame on
localImages[1].isVisible = true

-- listener function to play images one by one
local function onEveryFrame( event )
    --count
    myTimer = myTimer + 1

    --turn on next frame
    localImages[myTimer].isVisible = true

    --turn off last frame
    localImages[myTimer-1].isVisible = false

    --played all images in splash
    if myTimer == totalImages then
        --removes enterFrame
        Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", onEveryFrame )       
    end
end

-- assign the above function as an "enterFrame" listener
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", onEveryFrame )
```

No idea if this would work with the kind of images you are dealing with. Tell me how it goes! :)

Joe.

Comment: I tried your solution and the result were similar to using the Movieclip library. I'm guessing the delay is due to all images being loaded at once. I'll try loading in batches and see if it works.

Any other ideas you can suggest?

Comment: I kind of figured that might happen. Maybe if you optimize the png files? http://psydk.org/pngoptimizer

Honestly, I'm not really sure if this is possible in Corona.

If you share the png sequence with me I could try working with it.

Answer (score 0):

That's over 9M in images...wow...

The way Corona is designed you need to use sprites, so yeah try optimizing the pngs (I have had really good luck with TinyPNG (www.tinypng.com) and then combine them into a sprite sheet and use the animation functions.

Keep in mind you can use multiple sprite sheets, so you can break them down into 3 sheets of 100, 6 sheets of 50, etc.

Comment: But the Corona image guidelines state that images shouldn't exceed 2048x2048 texture size in any cases. That was the reason I didn't combine them in spritesheets.